# Getting rid of the author field in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I would like to have a bibliography without the author names (in case you are wondering, this is for part of a bibliography in a CV). I've tried to used the `clearlist` command but I guess I am using it wrong.

Here is my MWE which I compiled with `xelatex` - `biber` - `xelatex` - `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% to create a file when first processed
% \begin{filecontents}[<options>]{<filename>}
%   possible options: overwrite, nosearch, noheader
\begin{filecontents}{bib_2ndtry.bib}
@misc{A2020,
  author = {Author, A. and Author, B. and Author C.},
  year = {2020},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B2021,
  author = {Buthor, A.},
  year = {2021},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C2022,
  author = {Cuthor, A. and Cuthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2022},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% modifying bibliography items (well, trying to)
\AtEveryBibitem{
  \clearlist{author}
}

\addbibresource{bib_2ndtry.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In the final pdf, the authors are still included, see the attached image:

[image: final pdf]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

To do this with a sourcemap, put this in your preamble:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
     \step[fieldset=author, null]
   }
 }
}
```

This will remove all author fields from every cited entry before `biblatex` even sees the data. You can conditionalise this in arbitrary ways - just remove in certain entry types, just remove when certain other fields are present etc. by adding to this example. For example to only remove author fields in `misc` entry types, do:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{misc}
      \step[fieldset=author, null]
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Well, this was easier than I thought - just not clear to me which solution is "better" but I guess it depends on the use-case.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the [official biblatex documentation](https://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), I found the answer to my question: I need to replace `\clearlist{author}` by `\clearname{author}`.

Comment: Or you can use a sourcemap (see docs) to remove the field before biber/biblatex even process the .bib

Comment: @PLK am I right that you are referring to `\DeclareSourcemap` ? (which looks more complicated to me, i.e. I haven't been able to use it to remove the author field yet...)