# Removing "author" field with `\DeclareSourcemap` is inserting unneeded full stop and space

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am trying to remove the `author` field in my `beamer` presentation as I want the references to be as compact as possible. Using the [answer by PLK in response to the question "Getting rid of the author field in the bibliography"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656907/273733), namely:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{misc}
      \step[fieldset=author, null]
   }
 }
}
```

is removing the author field, however, when using this I am getting a full stop followed by a space before the `journal` entry:

[image]

I have looked at the `biblatex` GitHub repository before I asked here and could not see where the `author` field would include a full stop and a space in [the `\newbibmacro*{author/...}` definitions](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/cdabe89dae681734d3c9923057efb2368d6344c4/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2415), so I am not sure how to remove it. I added `%`'s after each line in the `\DeclareSourcemap` but it had no effect.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of the full stop and space please?

MWE (I included some styles so it somewhat matches my real document in case it is relevant):

```
% arara: pdflatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{ref.bib}
@Article{Mehandia2020,
  author                 = {Mehandia, Seema and Sharma, S. C. and Arya, Shailendra Kumar},
  journal                = {Biotechnol. Rep. (Amst)},
  title                  = {Isolation and characterization of an alkali and thermostable laccase from a novel Alcaligenes faecalis and its application in decolorization of synthetic dyes.},
  year                   = {2020},
  pages                  = {e00413},
  volume                 = {25},
  doi                    = {10.1016/j.btre.2019.e00413},
}
@Article{Murugesan2009,
  author                 = {Murugesan, Kumarasamy and Kim, Young-Mo and Jeon, Jong-Rok and Chang, Yoon-Seok},
  journal                = {J Hazard Mater.},
  title                  = {Effect of metal ions on reactive dye decolorization by laccase from Ganoderma lucidum.},
  year                   = {2009},
  pages                  = {523-9},
  volume                 = {168},
  doi                    = {10.1016/j.jhazmat.2009.02.075},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

%% --- These are just commands to match my current bib style
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1},}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
  }
%% ---- End

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656907/273733
\DeclareSourcemap{%
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{%
    \map{%
     \step[fieldset=author, null]%
   }%
 }%
}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{First slide Title}
    Text \cite{Mehandia2020}\cite{Murugesan2009}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try with a second map that really clears the title: `\map{\pertype{article}\step[fieldset=title, null]}`

Comment: It is embarrassing that I completely forgot about the `title` and its effect, your code worked when putting it into the `\DeclareSourcemap{}`, would you like to post that as answer?

Comment: Another great example why `\DeclareFieldFormat{<field name>}{}` is a bad way to suppress a field. It works OK-ish enough in many cases, because `biblatex` does some work behind the scenes explicitly to catch this situation, but if styles (or style modifications as in this case) do more complex stuff, it may break down because `biblatex` knows the field is non-empty, but cannot visibly print it.

Comment: @moewe yeah, I should have heeded your advice from a previous question of mine and answer of yours on [removing the title from `\footfullcite`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653833/273733). It is difficult to change styles when I am comfortable with this but I really need to. Linked to that answer so if anyone wants to follow your `\DeclareSourcemap` advice in the comments (as I should have) then they are signposted to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the title also in the sourcemap, and not only by changing its format:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{%
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{%
    \map{%
     \step[fieldset=author, null]%
   }%
   \map{\pertype{article}\step[fieldset=title, null]}
 }%
}
```